# Снова об уменьшительных формах имен

Tags: орфография

Тут уже много говорилось об уменьшительных суффиксах в женских именах, типа "Аничка-Анечка" и т.д. А как быть с именем Нелли? Оно заканчивается на И. Тогда какой будет уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс: "ичк" или "ечк"? НеллИчка или НеллЕчка?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Суффикс -ичк- пишется у существительных женского рода, образованных от основ на иц: лестничка (лестниц-а), луковичка (луковиц-а), пуговичка (пуговиц-а), умничка (умниц-а). В остальных случаях пишется суффикс -ечк-: пешечка (пешка), ситечко (сито), утречко (утро0, в том числе и  в именах собственных: Валечка, Зоечка, Иечка, Колечка, Фенечка, Юлечка (у этих слов основа не оканчивается на иц).

Имя Нелли тоже не заканчивается на -иц,  значит ***Нелечка***.